# Node JS session not work with Vue JS front

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, express-session

I am writing a Node JS backend application and Vue JS front, in the API I need session for keep authenticate the users

I use this components on backend server:

- express (4.18.2)
- express-session (1.17.3)
- connect-mongo (3.3.8)
- MongoDB 4.4.4

This is the boot code:

```
// import libs ---

import config from 'config'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'
import routes from './routes' // custom folder

import express from 'express'
import session from 'express-session'
import MongoStore from 'connect-mongo'

// set costant ---

const app = express()

const secret = config.get('secret')

// body parser ---

app.use(bodyParser.json())

// setup session ---

app.use(session({
    genid: function (req) { return uuidv4() }, // random id
    secret,
    store: MongoStore.create({ // connect to MongoDB fon Session storage
        mongoUrl: db.extendedURL,
        dbName: db.name,
        // autoRemove: 'native',
        // autoRemoveInterval: 10, // in minutes
        ttl: 7 * 24 * 3600 // in seconds
    }),
    cookie: { // cookies manage
        path: '/',
        maxAge: 6000000,
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: false,
        sameSite: false
    },
    stringify: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    rolling: false,
    unset: 'destroy'
}))

// set server port (now run at localhost:5000) ---

app.set('port', 5000)

// set route ---

app.use('/', routes)
```

In `./route` folder there are `index.js` imports perfectly

Here it is:

```
// import libs ---

import express from 'express'

const router = express.Router()

// routes ---

router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    const { body, session } = req

    try {
        session.user = body.user

        console.log('user', session.user)

        req.session.save(function (err) {
            if (err) return res.status(400).json({ message: err })

            return res.status(200).json({ message: 'You have successfully authenticated' })
        })
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: err })
    }
})

router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    const { session } = req

    try {
        console.log('session', session)

        return res.status(200).json(session)
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: err })
    }
})

export default router
```

When I try to call `localhost:5000/login` (post) I get all just fine, but when I call `localhost:5000/test` (get) I get a new session on the response and on MongoDB, it also happens whit multiple call on `localhost:5000/test`

Why `express-session` generate new session on every call? I really don't know, I spend few days in there and now i don't know how to do

---

### EDIT (12/Jan/2023)

I managet to get it to work using this very simple CORS configuration on NodeJS server boot code:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
    credentials: true
}))
```

and the header `withCredentials: true` on every simple http call from front

But this work only from `localhost:8080`
How can I do for call the Node JS server from other location without specify every IP addres?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow every origin you can do

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true
}))
```

or

```
app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: true
})
```

Source : [Why doesn't adding CORS headers to an OPTIONS route allow browsers to access my API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/why-doesnt-adding-cors-headers-to-an-options-route-allow-browsers-to-access-my)

Comment: `credentials: true` is the solution. Thank you very much